# Foreach in a foreach removing items from list

Tags: java, list, loops, foreach

I am creating a Java application based on who is it ?. Now I'm making a method where I want the other cards when a question is answered.

I have two lists:

A list is an ImageView list in which I have 24 image views that the cards must represent.

The other list is a list of 24 map objects.

Now I want to remove ImageViews from the ImageView list if an ID of an image view is the same as the name of a card in an ImageView.

I tried to do a foreach in a foreach and then remove an item from the list but I couldn't figure it out.

The method I created:

```
public List<ImageView> getImageViews(List<Card> newCards){

    for (ImageView imageView: new ArrayList<>(allCards)) {
        String imageName = imageView.getId().toLowerCase();

        for (Card card: new ArrayList<>(newCards)){
            String cardName = card.getName().toLowerCase();

            if (!imageName.equals(cardName)){
                allCards.remove(imageView);
            }
        }
    }

    return allCards;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers :

1) `allCards.remove(imageView);` will work only if equals() is overrided in `ImageView` consequently

2) This means that you want to remove the card if the join elements don't match :

```
if (!imageName.equals(cardName)){
    allCards.remove(imageView);
}
```

You will remove the element only when it matches while you said :

> Now I want to remove ImageViews from the ImageView list if an ID of an
>   image view is the same as the name of a card in an ImageView.

Something in this way would be better :

```
if (imageName.equals(cardName)){
    allCards.remove(imageView);
    break; // to go back to the outer loop
}
```

With Iterator you could make things more simple and without relying on equals() overriding :

```
public List<ImageView> getImageViews(List<Card> newCards){
    for (Iterator<ImageView> imageViewIt = allCards.iterator(); imageViewIt.hasNext();) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewIt.next();
        String imageName = imageView.getId().toLowerCase();
        for (Card card: newCards){
            String cardName = card.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (imageName.equals(cardName)){
                imageViewIt.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return allCards;
}
```

And with Java 8 you could even do that :

```
public List<ImageView> getImageViews(List<Card> newCards){
    allCards.removeIf(view -> 
                       newCards.anyMatch(card -> 
                                card.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(view.getId())
                     );
   return allCards;
}
```

This code works.

Comment: To come back to this question, the code works, only when I run it the second time allCards keeps the old values.

For example, if the program has run once, then the value of allCards is 8, which is also correct because 8 cards must be removed. Only if I run it again now that value remains 8 while I have to have the remaining cards.

Hopefully you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

> I  tried to do a foreach in a foreach and then remove an item from the
>   list but I couldn't figure it out.

Just use a normal `for` loop and, remove using the item from `allCards` based on the index.

**Code Snippet:**

```
public List<ImageView> getImageViews(List<Card> newCards){
    for (int i = 0; i < newCards.size(); i++) {
        String cardName = newCards.get(i).getName().toLowerCase();
        for (int j = 0; j < allCards.size(); j++){
            String imageName = allCards.get(j).getId().toLowerCase();
            if (imageName.equals(cardName)){
                allCards.remove(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return allCards;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, only...  it returns all 24 cards.

Comment: @TomvandenBogaart My bad, the `if` condition should not have `!` since you are trying to remove the item when name matches. Try with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Just make another array. Easier and less code. My Java may not be completely correct, it's been a while. But hopefully you'll get the idea:

```
public List<ImageView> getImageViews(List<Card> newCards){
 List<Card> returnObject = new List<Card>();
for (ImageView imageView: new ArrayList<>(allCards)) {
    String imageName = imageView.getId().toLowerCase();

    for (Card card: new ArrayList<>(newCards)){
        String cardName = card.getName().toLowerCase();

          //Instead of a NOT, let's look for an IS
        if (imageName.equals(cardName)){
            returnObject.add(imageView)
        }
    }
}

return allCards;
```

}